# Nav Element Disappears When Parents Element's Position Changed to Sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, navbar

I have a navbar div that has a title and a nav component. When the window gets small enough I collapse the nav element so have a burger to show and hide the nav element. Without changing the position attribute of the parent navbar div it works fine, however when I make the parent navbar div sticky I can no longer see the navbar move over onto the screen. I toggle the navbarHidden and navbarVisible class on the child nav element when the burger is clicked.

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 8vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(220, 220, 220);
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.navbar nav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 8vh;
    height: 92vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-right: 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    z-index: 1;
  }

.navbarHidden {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }

  .navbarVisible {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
```

The nav element still shows up when you inspect the page though.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, all you had to do was change the position on the nav element to fixed instead of absolute.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).